# Comparing an input form client with a file on server side using strcmp

Tags: c, network-programming

It is a school assignment and I need build a network that client sends a input to server and server will compare it to a file's content, if the input is exsist on the file as a keyword, server will send back a message of that item in the file. the server will send a message of no match found if the input does not exsist on the file.

---

I was givern a template of server.cpp and client.cpp by the instructor in order to build a simple network, all I have to do is write the parts of read file, compare input with the file. So far the program of server can send back the item if I input the keyword correctly on client side. the problem is when I input anything that it is not the keyword, server side breaks down and reports me there is a memory problem.

---

I am not familiar with pointer and memory in C++, so I can't find out what the problem is, thus I am looking for the reason of occuring this problem and ways of solution. Here is that part of code:

```
typedef struct {
int Number;
char* Subject_Code;
char* Subject_Title;
char* Timetable;
char* Instru_Name;
} time;

int parseNumber(char *line){
return atoi(line + 8);}
char *parseCode(char *line){
return line + 14;}
char *parseTitle(char *line){
return line + 15;}
char *parseTime(char *line){
return line + 11;}
char *parseInst(char *line){
return line + 13;}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char szBuff[1024];
int msg_len;
int addr_len;
struct sockaddr_in local, client_addr;

SOCKET sock, msg_sock;
WSADATA wsaData;

char *fileLocation ="data.txt";
FILE *file = fopen(fileLocation, "r");

if (!file)printf("%s\n",strerror(errno));
char buffer[1024];
time times[128];
int timeindex = 0;

    if (fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), file)){
        char *line = strtok(buffer, "\n");
        times[timeindex].Number = parseNumber(line);

        // 0 number, 1 code, 2 title, 3 table, 4 name
        int lineType = 1;
        while ((line= strtok(NULL, "\n"))){
            if(lineType == 5)
            {
                timeindex++;
                lineType = 0;
            }
            switch (lineType) {
            case 0:
                {
                    times[timeindex].Number = parseNumber(line);
                    break;
                }
            case 1:
                {
                    times[timeindex].Subject_Code = parseCode(line);
                    break;
                }
            case 2:
                { 
                    times[timeindex].Subject_Title = parseTitle(line);
                    break;
                }
            case 3:
                {
                    times[timeindex].Timetable = parseTime(line);
                    break;
                }
            case 4:
                {
                    times[timeindex].Instru_Name = parseInst(line);
                    break;
                }
            }
            lineType++; 
        }
    }

...
msg_len = recv(msg_sock, szBuff, sizeof(szBuff), 0);
...

if (msg_len > 0){       

    for (int c = 0; c <= timeindex; c++){
        if(strcmp(szBuff,times[c].Subject_Title)==0 || strcmp(szBuff,times[c].Subject_Code)==0 || strcmp(szBuff,times[c].Instru_Name)==0){
            msg_len = send(msg_sock, times[c].Timetable, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            break;
        }
    }




        msg_len = send(msg_sock, "No matchs were found.\n",20, 0);
```

}

Comment: This appears to be C, and not C++ as there is no specific C++ code. Retag to C if this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`strtok()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) requires its input string to be null terminated. [`fread()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) does not append the null terminator (nor does it have any room to in the posted code) and `buffer` is not initialized. If permitted use `fgets()` instead of `fread()` and `strtok()` for processing lines. Otherwise, read one less character with `fread()` and ensure the last character in `buffer` is `'\0'`.

[`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) requires its input strings to be null terminated and `recv()` does not append the null terminator and `szBuff` is not initialized. Read one less character with `recv()` and ensure the last character in `szBuff` is `'\0'`.

If `times[c].Timetable` is pointing to memory that has less bytes than `buffer` then this will be invalid accessing memory:

```
msg_len = send(msg_sock, times[c].Timetable, sizeof(buffer), 0);
```

Only write the number of characters in `times[c].Timetable` if it is the case that there is a difference in size.